# Static Image behind JTextPane text in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane, jtextpane

So I have a JScrollPane that I need to scroll (vertically only) through centered word-wrapping text. Behind the text should be a static, non-scrollable partially transparent image.

My first approach was to add the image to the JTextPane in the JScrollPane. This failed due to forcing the image to scroll out of where it exists.

My second approach was to make the JTextPane's background transparent and display the image behind the JTextPane on a JLabel. This failed due to the JTextPane's bacakground not being able to be transparent within the JScrollPane.
-Now I could make it transparent, but it would leave behind corrupted, miscolored, and misplaced text along with the scrollbar randomly appearing over the JTextPane.

My third approach was using a JTextArea instead and displaying the image behind the it. This failed due to the JTextArea not being able to center text.

My fourth approach was to use a JLabel to display the text. This failed due to the JLabel not being able to word wrap. Although a few people seemed to have html fixes for this, none worked as they all wrapped at incorrect spots.

So I'm not sure what I should try next, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the JTextPane to the JScrollPane, then adding the JScrollPane to the center of a JPanel using a BorderLayout, then drawing the image on the JPanel with the paintComponent method.

Comment: Above suggestion should work but 1) you will need to make the text pane,  scroll pane and the viewport of the scroll pane transparent in order to see the image and 2) part of the image will be covered by the scrollbar(s) of the scroll pane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My second approach was to make the JTextPane's background transparent

Yes, this is necessary to see any background image

> Behind the text should be a static, non-scrollable partially transparent image.

You want to do custom painting of the `JViewport` of the scroll pane to display the image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ViewportBackground
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
//      JTextPane textArea = new JTextPane();
        textArea.setOpaque(false);

        Image image = new ImageIcon("mong.jpg").getImage();

        JViewport viewport = new JViewport()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                //  add custom painting here. 
                //  For a scaled image you can use:

                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewport(viewport);
        scrollPane.setViewportView( textArea );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Viewport Background");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```